# How to show that the following functions are primitive recursive?

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

I want to solve the following problem :

Let $f_1(x), f_2(x), g_1(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ and $g_2(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ be primitive recursive functions. Also, let $h_1, h_2$ be defined as :

$h_1(x, 0) = f_1(x)$

$h_2(x, 0) = f_2(x)$

$h_1(x, t + 1) = g_1(x, t, h_1(x, t), h_2(x, t))$

$h_2(x, t+1) = g_2(x, t, h_1(x, t), h_2(x, t))$.

Show that $h_1, h_2$ are primitive recursive.

The problem also notes that we could use the function ${\lambda}(x, t) = 2^{h_1(x, t)}\cdot 3^{h_2(x, t)}$.

I do not have much knowledge on this area and it is now that I am trying to be familiar. My thoughts  is to :

Define $K(x,y) =  \langle h_1(x, y), h_2(x, y)\rangle$ and show that $K$ is primitive recursive function.
So, if we define $K$ using primitive recursion, we get that :
$K(x, 0) = \langle f_1(x), f_2(x)\rangle$ and $K(x, t+1) = j (t, K(x, t), x)$ and

$j(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \langle g_1(x_4, l(x_3), r(x_3), p(x_3)), g_2(x_4, l(x_3), r(x_3), p(x_3))\rangle$.

Now, we have that $j$ is obtained by recursion and composition of $g_1, g_2$ and initial functions and so, $j$ is primitive recursive. Hence, $K$ is primitive recursive. Therefore, $h_1, h_2$ are defined to be $l(g(x, y))$ and $r(g(x, y))$ respectively, which are both primitive recursive.

Does all these make sense and complete the proof?
Otherwise, is there another way that someone can show me on how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: Indeed! I was just writing in a hurry! Thank you though :)

Comment: And I'm the subjunctive monster: you can't use the indicative after "let" - it really has to be "let ... be ...".

Comment: I will change that. English is not my native language, so making small mistakes that do not even change the meaning of the problem is not that bad, especially when the question is mathematical. But thank you anyway.

Comment: I've already made the change - please don't worry about your grammar. Let me now try to help with the mathematics: your answer makes sense if you are working with a definition of primitive recursive function that includes functions from $\Bbb{N}^m$ to $\Bbb{N}^n$ for $n > 1$. If your primitive recursive functions are restricted to return natural numbers, rather than tuples of natural numbers then you will need to use some kind of encoding, perhaps like the function $\lambda$ that has been suggested to you.

Comment: @RobArthan There is a note at the end of the exercise saying that the proof would work out in the same way if for any $n>1$, we replace $x$ by $n$-tuple of variables/inputs. So I guess that the primitive recursive functions can return tuples of natural numbers. If not, I do not seem to understand how to solve the problem using that function $\lambda$. Any help?